# How to fix missing functions directory problem with Netlify continuous deployment?

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I followed steps from the official [Netlify Docs:](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/05/28/deploy-in-seconds-with-netlify-cli/)

I run `npm run build` and building process was finish correctly.

Then the docs suggest to run `netlify deploy --open` but it gives me the following error:

> No such directory C:\Users\Concierge\Downloads\prod\ColorApp2\MaterialColorPickerCOM\functions! Did you forget to create a functions folder or run a build?

I tried to use command `netlify deploy --prod` as recommended by one user but it gives me the same error. The website is visible on my Netlify account but doesn't work:  [Here is the link](https://flamboyant-swartz-d887d2.netlify.com/)

Do you guys have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

#### Not building Netlify functions

If you are not building functions, then make sure to not include a functions target directory in your `netlify.toml`

```
[build]
  command = "npm run build"
  publish = "build"
  # functions = "functions"
```

#### Including Netlify functions

If you are including Netlify lamdbda functions with your project. Make sure after a build that there is a directory created that is specified in the functions value.

The example below expects there to be functions in a `/functions` directory after a build prior to a deploy or it will fail.

`netlify.toml`

```
[build]
  command = "npm run build"
  publish = "build"
  functions = "functions"
```

Comment: what is a netlify.toml I dont even have this file in my folder

Comment: ok, so the netlify.toml file isn't a requirement on Netlify, but a config file for the build environment on Netlify that you could use instead of having to maintain some of the configuration within the admin gui that devs can use as an alternative to have the settings in a more centralized location next to code. https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/#sample-netlify-toml-file

Comment: I got the error `Error: functions directory is undefined, did you forget to set it in netlify.toml?` with `ntl functions:invoke` - testing a function. My solution was that I forgot to start the local server with `ntl dev`. Should I post it as answer? It has nothing to do with deployment as asked in the title.

Comment: No, the issue in the OP was not putting the functions in the default location on build.

Comment: you can also write that there is a separate entry for `functions` possible: `[functions]` with a `directory` key. What happened to me when I run `ntl functions:invoke` from `cli`: I was in the wrong local dir and the functions dir was obviously not found and I got the error.